# Remesh breaks the surface of object

Tags: mesh, sculpting

I've just started to learn Blender by following a tutorial on youtube. My problem is that when I remesh this object, the surface breaks. I don't know what causes this since I'm following the tutorial step by step, and nothing happens similar to this. Any ideas why, is this a bug? 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Make sure the mesh is closed, I can't tell from the screenshot, because it's flat shaded. 
Use *Merge Vertices by Distance* to confirm.

Comment: Hello, thank you for suggestion but it still didn't work for me. Faces broke again. I created a new object and tried remeshing again and it worked. I still don't have a clue why it didn't work in the first place though.

Comment: I've just had the same problem in another object, I found a solution. https://old.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/euwbhj/remesh_results_in_mesh_full_of_holes/ I used the 3D Print Addon to find holes in my mesh, and got rid of them.

Answer (score 0):

this happens when the surface is not solid and has holes. face is missing somewhere.